# C++ Function that is not being called has to be present or code explodes

Tags: c++, debugging

So I have this really weird problem where if this function doesn't exist in my code it won't work. It can be any name, it just has to exist. I even have a `exit(EXIT_FALURE)` statement in my code, and it will run if that is present. (Note this is happening on multiple computers).

Basically I have to have code that looks like this:

```
void dosomething()
{
  Camera dummyCamera;
  dummyCamera.refreshTransform(0,0);
}
```

But I can rename the function like so, and it still works

```
void thisStillWorks()
{
  Camera dummyCamera;
  dummyCamera.refreshTransform(0,0);
}
```

Without changing anything else in the code. This function is never called explicitly. However, if I comment the method body out, one can notice the difference at runtime.

Here's a video of this weird thing...

http://youtu.be/PIyGOoMAa6Y

Solutions that have not worked:
- Clean data
- Comment out code
- Look for #define in code base
- Delete derived data
- Setting a breakpoint in the function body (it is just skipped)

If you are really curious you can clone our repository here (you'll need to install the dependencies yourself):

https://github.com/fnk0/MarcusGameEngine

Comment: @RyanDawkins: Cloning the project does not work out of the box. Some libraries are missing. (I'm going to bed now...)

Comment: @RyanDawkins: can you break the debugger by setting a breakpoint in `ryanRedneck`?  Perhaps the call stack will shed light on how it is getting invoked.

Comment: @PeterHuene I did try a breakpoint and it just skips the breakpoint! I guess I could have demonstrated that in the video. I'll add that to the main post.

Comment: ODR violation, and that call makes the instance of the inline function called that persists be the one defined in this translation unit?

Comment: Is it possible for you to create a simple command line version of the code that can be analyzed to see what the problem is? Your video is using XCode.  Does this happen in other environments? Creating an MCVE of the problem so that its something that we can see and look at more easily without trying to debug an entire project would make for a better question.

Answer (score 2):

Some of my guesses.

- My best guess is that you have memory corruption and you have overwritten a vtable value with this function pointer totally coincidentally. Or some sort of invalid jump is taken, which gets to become visible because of different instruction padding. To investigate, use valgrind.
- If this is not the case, I guess your compiler/linker is sort of broken. Try recompiling everything from scratch (by deleting all your .o files).
- I could imagine a scenario where your library gets linked dynamically and you invoke dynamically loaded methods by index or something.
- You did:

  ```
  #define void void myDefaultFunctionNameIamATroll() \/\/
  ```

Comment: This does happen on multiple computers. This is something I'm working on with a group.

Comment: Where would the .o files be stored for xcode?

Comment: Well, then my best bet is memory corruption and to use valgrind to figure out what is going wrong (which is pretty hard, or impossible to do on iOS simulator). But first, make sure there is no troll in your team that hid a #define somewhere. Do a global project-wide search for "#define" and "dummyCamera" and "refreshTransform".

Comment: In Xcode, you can go to the organized and click the "delete derived data" button.

Comment: I just did a global search, there is no define.

Comment: I added a list of things I've tried now. So I won't be spamming here.

Comment: Also, try recompiling without optimizations. And hopefully a crash will be triggered you can start investigating.

Comment: The Clang Sanitizers might be enough instead of running full Valgrind.

Answer (score 1):

There are good chances that this is caused by memory corruption. Valgrind will help you here. Changing behaviors between debug/release mode and compiler optimization levels is another way to check this.

Basically depending on how your code gets loaded in memory, different places can be overwritten by invalid pointer accesses so defining a body for your function will change the layout and prevent hard crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Your `refreshTransform` function is implicitly `inline` as it is defined within the body of the `class`.

This means that if there are two different compilation units that define an implementation of `void Camera::refreshTransform(float, float)`, all but one will be silently discarded.  If the implementations differ, your program is ill formed, and no diagnostic is required.

In short, due to the order header files are included, preprocessor symbols, exposed overrides of functions called in that function, or the same errors recursively applied to each and every `inline` and `template` and in-class method and function invoked from that function, there are two different implementations of some code.

When you invoke it within that particular compilation unit, which some `inline` function is marked as used, and the "discard all but one" ends up with a different one picked.

Now, this could also be some other one definition rule violation -- the size of some type differs in different compilation units, the value of some variable or constant, etc.

To fix this, you can stop `inline`ing methods.  You can stick `inline` functions and `template` functions in anonymous namespaces.  You can track down how the function in question behaves with and without your change.  And search recursively.